# Android Base64 Audio File Encode / Decode

Tags: java, android, base64

**Doing:** I am currently recording voice and saving it as a file in sdCard which is running  playing fine in MediaPlayer.

**What i want:** When i encode this file intoBase64 and send to server, everything goes fine. But When i decode the Base64 String into audio.m4a file, it is not running in MediaPlayer.

I had tried .m4a , .wav but all in vain.
The problem is in encoding. Because when i decode a file sent from the same iOS app, it runs fine in MediaPlayer.

I know its very basic and alot of help is there to encode decode but nothing is working. Following is my approach:

```
private void encodeAudio(String selectedPath) {

byte[] audioBytes;
try {

    // Just to check file size.. Its is correct i-e; Not Zero
    File audioFile = new File(selectedPath);
    long fileSize = audioFile.length();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath));
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int n;
    while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
        baos.write(buf, 0, n);
    audioBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    // Here goes the Base64 string
    _audioBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(audioBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

} catch (Exception e) {
    DiagnosticHelper.writeException(e);
}

}
```

**And Decoding in the following way:**

```
 private void decodeAudio(String base64AudioData, File fileName, String path, MediaPlayer mp) {

try {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    fos.write(Base64.decode(base64AudioData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    fos.close();

    try {

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(path);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        DiagnosticHelper.writeException(e);

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
```

Please point if i am doing anything wrong.
Thanks

Comment: do convert your converted base64 to you desired file, then play if it play fine then check what is receiving on server do cross check them, if same then it will be encoding issue, as I know. Let me know if it help..

Comment: you are sending the encoded string to the server and if you try to decode the 'server'-string something goes wrong? Maybe soemthing went wrong by data transfer from/to the server?

Comment: No server is also sending me same base64 in json @zypro

Comment: mhm... The same string but different result? The server-string is in the same format and type? Maybe there are some additional brackets arround... ?

Comment: no brackets @zypro

Comment: `decodeAudio(String base64AudioData, .....`. You are not showing how you call this function. So we do not know the content of the parameters.

Comment: You better remove all the mediaplayer stuff. Just post code that encodes a file and decodes it back. Then tell all the file and string lengths.

Comment: Read the post carefully function is described decodeAudio(String base64AudioData,..)

Comment: Show how you call it was the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is before relasing audio i was converting audio into `Base64 String` thats why **Decoded** file is corrupt !! Cheers